# Embedding CodePen Calorie Script - jquery error

Tags: theme-development, jquery, embed, scripts

I'm trying to embed this code: https://codepen.io/jme11/pen/zMVJVX

into my Wordpress about fitness, but I don't know why it's not working correctly -

I've downloaded the export of the code, which works perfectly in the standalone HTML (+ js and css) file (specifically the completed form will display in the results div.

I've then embedded the HTML in my Wordpress template page - it appears on the front end fine,
I've properly linked in the css and js in the same order as in the HTML - and checking them in (View Source shows they are connected)

Completing the form and hitting calculate DOES do something (it shows amounts the protein / fat / carb field) - however, the results div (with calories per day) does not appear.

I think it might have something to do with jquery as I get this error in the console (but don't understand):

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function
at calcDailyCals (script.js?ver=1.0:51)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (script.js:3)
at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

Can anyone help? Just not sure why it would work in the standalone HTML file and not on a Wordpress page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery script added was conflicting with the slim jquery that was also being loaded - by bootstrap footer code.

I replaced the slim jquery in the bootstrap footer includes with the full min jquery and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To use jquery in Wordpress you have to use the jQuery function instead of $, this is done to avoid naming conflicts. A good way to return the jquery function to its original $ is to wrap the code inside a block like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    //code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @Patareco - I've done that but get the same (`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function`) error. Do you know how I can modify this code to allow it to work, even if it removes the fade and just appears? `$('#m-results').fadeOut('fast',function(){
    $(this).html('<h3>Estimated Daily Calories: ' + result + '</h3>').fadeIn('fast');
  });`

Comment: try adding this to the functions.php file of your theme:
function theme_enqueue_myscripts() {
 wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_myscripts' );